# Generators in Javascript into the new ECMA standard

Tags: javascript

Generators are being introduced in the new version of the ECMA standards.
Could any one suggest the importance and the usage of generators in the present Javascript world?
Examples of generators in real world problems will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

## Starters

I'd suggest to look at:

- the [ECMAScript Harmony Project](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:harmony)'s wiki page on [Generators](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators),
- the [Mozilla Developer Doc on Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators),
- the [JavaScript Tips](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips) page of the [jslibs](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/) project,
- the Google [Traceur Compiler](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/)'s page on [JavaScript Language Features](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures#Generators),
- [SO questions for "javascript generator yield"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20%20generator%20yield).

A simple example is given in the [Mozilla Developer Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/) introducing the [new features of JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Generators):

```
function fib() {
  var i = 0, j = 1;
  while (true) {
    yield i;
    var t = i;
    i = j;
    j += t;
  }
}

var g = fib();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(g.next());
}
```

Others are available in the documents listed above.

## Real-World

For real world examples, you can for instance see:

- Google's own [Traceur-Compiler](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/)'s tests for [EndYieldGenerator](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/source/browse/test/feature/Yield/EndYieldGenerator.js?spec=svnb940a87c95a1b62910b11d9dfc719123ecb77d6e&r=b940a87c95a1b62910b11d9dfc719123ecb77d6e), and [SwitchGenerator](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/source/browse/test/feature/Yield/SwitchGenerator.js?r=b940a87c95a1b62910b11d9dfc719123ecb77d6e),
- or even the whole [test battery for the `yield` keyword](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/source/browse/test/feature/Yield/?r=b940a87c95a1b62910b11d9dfc719123ecb77d6e) in Google's [traceur-compiler](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler),
- or the AcidMonkey tests, for instance this [Pi Generator](http://code.google.com/searchframe#ct6VDNauLAY/trunk/cpp/acidmonkey/dep/js/src/tests/js1_7/geniter/pi-generator.js&q=generator%20yield%20lang:%5Ejavascript$&type=cs).

Answer (score 0):

I think Generators are best explained in the following article: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

This might be also useful: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-18-progress/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Posting links is best left to comments, unless you're going to expand on the contents of the linked page.